# How to compute the second derivative of a function of a stochastic process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

#### Background

Suppose we have a state $\mathbf{x}(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times 1}$ evolving according to
\begin{equation}
      \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}(t) = \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}(t)) \mathrm{d}t + \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x}(t)) \mathrm{d}\mathbf{w}(t),
   \end{equation}
where $\mathbf{F}: \mathbb{R}^{d \times 1} \to \mathbb{R}^{d \times 1}$ is a Lipschitz continuous drift coefficient and $\mathbf{G}: \mathbb{R}^{d \times 1} \to \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ is a Lipschitz continuous diffusion coefficient. $\mathbf{w}(t)$ is the standard Weiner process.

Now, suppose we have an "energy function" $E(\mathbf{x}): \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ that (according to Ito's Lemma) evolves with the SDE of $\mathbf{x}(t)$ as
$$
\mathrm{d}E(\mathbf{x}) = \nabla_\mathbf{x} E(\mathbf{x})^\top \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}) \mathrm{d}t + \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Tr}\left( \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x}) \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x})^\top \nabla_\mathbf{x}^2 E(\mathbf{x}) \right) \mathrm{d}t + \nabla_\mathbf{x} E(\mathbf{x})^\top \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x}) \mathrm{d}\mathbf{w}(t),
$$
which is essentially the "velocity" of the energy function.

#### Question

How can I compute the "acceleration" of the energy function? Would it be an SDE equal to $\mathrm{d}E/\mathrm{d}t$? Or, would it be equal to $\mathrm{d}^2E$? I guess Ito's lemma would need to be applied again.

Could I apply Ito's lemma to the drift and diffusion coefficients of $\mathrm{d}E$, i.e. by letting
\begin{align}
A(\mathbf{x}) &= \nabla_\mathbf{x} E(\mathbf{x})^\top \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}) \mathrm{d}t + \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Tr}\left( \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x}) \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x})^\top \nabla_\mathbf{x}^2 E(\mathbf{x}) \right) \mathrm{d}t \\
B(\mathbf{x}) &= \nabla_\mathbf{x} E(\mathbf{x})^\top \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x})
\end{align}
and computing
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}A(\mathbf{x}) =& \nabla_\mathbf{x} A(\mathbf{x})^\top \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}) \mathrm{d}t + \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Tr}\left( \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x}) \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x})^\top \nabla_\mathbf{x}^2 A(\mathbf{x}) \right) \mathrm{d}t + \nabla A(\mathbf{x})^\top \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x}) \mathrm{d}\mathbf{w}(t) \\
\mathrm{d}B(\mathbf{x}) =& \nabla_\mathbf{x} B(\mathbf{x})^\top \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}) \mathrm{d}t + \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Tr}\left( \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x}) \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x})^\top \nabla_\mathbf{x}^2 B(\mathbf{x}) \right) \mathrm{d}t + \nabla B(\mathbf{x})^\top \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x}) \mathrm{d}\mathbf{w}(t),
\end{align}
then
$$
\mathrm{d}^2E(\mathbf{x}) = \mathrm{d}A(\mathbf{x})\mathrm{d}t + \mathrm{d}B(\mathbf{x})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{w}(t)?
$$
Would this make sense as the "acceleration" of $E$?

Comment: What $d^2 E$ means from a stochastic process prospective? Because SDEs are basically integral equations. If you need "second derivatives" i suggest using the Stratonovich integral instead of Ito

Comment: Yes, this is a thing people have been trying and to some degree failing for a very long time. If you absolutely must you can resort to Malliavin calculus or distributional derivatives, but nearly every physical equation that was generalised to be stochastic nearly always gets around having to take second derivatives creatively.

Comment: @Marco, any suggestion on how to apply the Stratonovich approach? What steps would I need to take?

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis, can you give some examples where second derivative need to be taken creatively? What are the key capabilities of Malliavin calculus in my case?

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is trying to make a stochastic Euler Lagrange equation. You have to be extremely careful where you add the noise else you might differentiate $dW$/second derivative of $W$ which is not allowed. However if you Legendre transform to Hamilton's equations, which are first order (so safe), you simply "add noise to the Poisson bracket" stress free.

Comment: Updated the question to show how I have already tried to apply Ito's lemma.

Comment: When you write
$$
dE_t=A(x_t)dt+B(x_t) dW_t
$$
what it really means is
$$
E(x_t)=E(x_0)+\int_0^t A(x_s) ds + \int_0^t B(x_s) dW_s
$$
so the principal problem is that $d^2E$ need to be defined first.
 I suggested to use the Stratonovich integral because at least you dont have to deal with the second order terms, but now that i look a bit into it i don't think there is an easy way to define what you need. For your solution: Can you write it in the extended form? How does it look when you write then as a stochastic integral?

Comment: I guess it is an ill-defined problem. The way it is now is that $\mathbf{x}(t)$ is a continuous, but non-smooth, trajectory, with a discontinuous "velocity", which is not differentiable. Hence, "acceleration" is unobtainable. I guess I would need to instead consider a second-order SDE, where the "velocity" evolves according to an SDE and the "position" evolves deterministically according to the "velocity".

Answer (score 1):

To be clear as you can see from your SDE formula, the process is not-differentiable $E(x)=...\int g(t) dW_{t}$ because Brownian motion isn't. So you don't even have first time-derivative. You only get at best Holder continuity for $Y_{t}:=E(x_{t})$.